# Cocos2D + Box2D: A lot of parse issues when running on device

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I´m building a game using the Cocos2D framework and the Box2D engine.

When I run the game in my simulator it works just fine. However, when I try to run it on my device, I get around 20 issues, most of them  "parse" issues and "semantic" issues.

This is some of the issues:

```
ccMacros.h
(!)Parse Issue
    Unknown type name 'NSUInteger'


CFDictionary.h
(!)Parse Issue
    Expected identifier or '('

(!)Semantic Issue
    Function cannot return function type 'int(const void*)'

(!)Parse Issue
    Unknown type name 'CF_EXPORT'
```

Honestly, I´ve have no idea what´s causing this and Google could not help me either.

For what it´s worth, I´m using cocos2d 2.0 and my device is a iPod Touch 4th generation.

Any advice on how to figure this mess out would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: By request, some lines that causes issues:

```
typedef const void *    (*CFDictionaryRetainCallBack)(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value);
typedef void        (*CFDictionaryReleaseCallBack)(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value);
typedef CFStringRef (*CFDictionaryCopyDescriptionCallBack)(const void *value);
typedef Boolean     (*CFDictionaryEqualCallBack)(const void *value1, const void *value2);
typedef CFHashCode  (*CFDictionaryHashCallBack)(const void *value);
```

Comment: version of Xcode and actual lines of code for each error would help

Comment: Using version 4.4.1. I´m not sure those lines would help, I didn´t write any of them. But I´ll update with some lines that causes the issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue when I have created a class inside my project named "Block" (thus, "Block.h" and "Block.mm"). This caused exactly the same issues that you're facing.

Check your recently added header files if they shadow some system ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the file names of the classes which work with box2d to end in  .mm instead of .m

Comment: I´ve made sure all implementations files add with .mm, really frustrating problem. Could be anything in the build settings? Thanks for replying anyway.